# Laravel 5 retrieve first record within wherepivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

```
*document* [id, core_document]  
*person* [id, name]  
*documentPersonsRole* [document_id, person_id, role] (where role could be accused or victim)
```

Is it possible to create a quick method to return the first record from a belongs-to-many relationship? Here is my code, from the model file:

```
public function documentPersonsRole()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Person', 'document_person_role')
        ->withPivot('role')
        ->withTimestamps();
}

public function accused()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Person', 'document_person_role')
        ->withPivot('role')
        ->wherePivot('role', 'accused')
        ->withTimestamps();
}

public function victim()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Person', 'document_person_role')
            ->withPivot('role')
            ->wherePivot('role', 'victim')
            ->withTimestamps();    
}
```

When I call this:

```
App\Models\Document::with('accused')->first()
=> App\Models\Document {#3118
     id: 1,
     core_document: "Iure aut eum aut ex et. Magni aliquam illo voluptatem non repellat. Maxime occaecati reiciendis veniam quod neque reiciendis dolores. Eaque quis molestiae dolorem. Et rerum veniam animi sit beatae inventore voluptas. Aut ea atque nulla quis quam incidunt iusto voluptas. Aut corrupti voluptas minima unde dicta vero aut veritatis. Voluptas vitae nam mollitia quasi porro id quod ut.",         
     accused: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3127
       all: [
         App\Models\Person {#3139
           id: 41,
           name: "Jamie",               
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3138
             document_id: 1,
             person_id: 41,
             role: "accused",
             created_at: "2018-10-24 03:55:23",
             updated_at: "2018-10-24 03:55:23",
           },
         },
       ],
     },
   }
```

And you can see that ***accused*** is a collection with only one record, and when I receive this on client side, I have to extract this record from array, but I want to work with object.

When I try something like this:

```
public function accused()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Person', 'document_person_role')
            ->withPivot('role')
            ->wherePivot('role', 'accused')
            ->withTimestamps()->first();
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder::addEagerConstraints()'

How can I use first() to retrieve and object in accused instead of array with one record.

Comment: Not completely sure, but have you tried `belongsToOne` instead of `belongsToMany`?

Comment: @i-- I'm pretty sure `belongsToOne()` doesn't exist

Comment: `->belongsTo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you accessing it?

You might have to call the method directly, instead of letting Laravel try to dynamically get it via a magic method:

`$accused = $document->accused()`

Or, define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):

```
public function getAccusedAttribute() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Person', 'document_person_role')
        ->withPivot('role')
        ->wherePivot('role', 'accused')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->first();
}
```

Which would allow you to use `$accused = $document->accused`;

Normally, when you define a method `bar()` that returns a relationship, when you call `$foo->bar` Laravel will hook the `__get()` magic method in PHP to call `bar()->get()` somewhere behind the scenes. Since you're already running the query by using `first()` on the relationship, Laravel was expecting a relationship to run a query against but ended up getting your model.

**Edit:**

If you still want the ability to eager load the relationships, here's another method:

In Document:

```
public function accusedPeople()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Person', 'document_person_role')
        ->withPivot('role')
        ->wherePivot('role', 'accused')
        ->withTimestamps();
}

public function getFirstAccusedAttribute()
{
    return $this->accusedPeople
        ->first();
}
```

In the controller:

```
// If you're eager loading, the relationship to eager load is `accusedPeople`
$document = Document::with('accusedPeople')->first();

// The accused person is accessed with the `first_accused` property
$accused = $document->first_accused;

// if you're returning the model directly for json:
// $document->append('first_accused');
```

Comment: I do like this, but it turns out doing it wrong.  
getAccusedAttribute() - this function let using this and retrieve a relation:   

    $document->accused

Thanks!  
But how does I use it in controller instead of this  

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $query = Document::with('accused');
    
        $documents = $query->get();
    
        return response()->json(
            $documents,
            200
        );
    }
To use after receiving data on the client: *$document->accused*

Comment: @MaximStogniy sorry, I'm not sure what your comment is saying?

Comment: I fix my comment, can you help?

Comment: @MaximStogniy you can't eager load it in its current form (can't use `with('accused')`)

Comment: Any ideas how can I collect an object document, which includes for example [id, core_document, accused(object)] ?
Or the only option is an array with a single element that will need to be converted into an object on the client?

Comment: @MaximStogniy I updated the answer, does that help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately still an array

Comment: @MaximStogniy what is an array?

Comment: If I do all correct, it contains one element - person which is accused

Comment: $document->first_accused will return one Person model from a Document. In my controller example I used Document::get() instead of Document::first() so that I could demonstrate how it's used with eager loading, is that where you're getting an array (of documents)?

Comment: But I have a question of this: $accused = $document->first_accused;
I think this is a mistake and it will be right like this: $document->test= $document->first_accused;

Comment: @MaximStogniy are you turning this into json? You might need to do `$document->append('first_accuser')` if you want it to appear in the response

Comment: Yes, I am turning into json. Your way to adding is well to, I'll use it)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
App\Models\Document::with(['accused' => function($query){
    $query->first();
}])->first()
```

this will query `accused` to return only the 1st row.

Comment: Still returns an array
$vm0.documents[0].accused
[{…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: {…}
length: 1
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array